# Need help centering a div class on page

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS and I've been trying to figure out how to center this div class called `.content` in the middle of the page that is wrapped around my table data. I have googled around and what I have found is that I should set the left margin to `0` and the right margin to `auto` but what I get when I do this is the entire table stays on the left side of the page.

Right now I have the `margin-left` at `500px` trying to to get it close to the center of the page but I think if I do it this way it will not be centered on other screens with different resolutions and I would like for it to be centered no matter what the screen size is.

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>Table</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Data 2</th>
                <th>Data 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    border: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: dashed;
}
h1 {
    border: 1px;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: dashed;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    border: 1px;
    border-color: orange;
    border-style: dashed;
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin_right: auto;
    margin-left: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
.content th {
    border: 1px;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.content td {
    border: 1px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: dashed;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Give `.content` a fixed width. Also, `margin_right` is not a valid property. You probably mean `margin-right`, but you don't need to set it since you have `margin-left` specified. Also, your question does not follow [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `.content` does not have a fixed width you cannot use `margin:0px auto` which would center the content. In your case u can just it on the `table` element like this:

```
table{
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

but you need to remove `display:inline-block` from `.content` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Centering means equal margins from left and right. Therefore, side margins should be set to auto, like so:

.content {margin: 0 auto}

...where 0 is the margins from top AND bottom and auto are margins from left AND right

I'd remove inline-block from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update .content as

```
.content {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px;
 border-style:dashed;
 border-color: orange;
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left:auto; #make this as auto
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

However this will align .content at the center horizontally, but if you want .content in center vertically then

```
.content{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case in particular, the best solution is to adjust the two "margin" properties inside your .content class declaration from:

> margin-left:500px;
>      margin_right: auto;

To:

> margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;

Be aware that "margin_right" needs to have a hyphen ('-') not an underscore.

Comment: Man, people are so fast answering here, I thought I'd be the first since it was only 5 seconds old!  The power of SO, I guess and why I have such a low score.... Too many smarter people on here!!!