# How to display my page in center with 20% margin on both side?

Tags: html, css

I want to display my page in center (width: 80% auto;) I'm using Center class but it is not working. Can anyone tell me how to display my page leave 20% margin on both side.

Here is my Source Code (HTML)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
<title>GR PROVIDER</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="center">
<div class="Header">
<div class="heading">
<h2> Gulf Resources Provider </h2>
</div>
<div class="socialmedia">
<ul>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/Facebook.jpg"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/LinkedIn.jpg"></a> </li>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/Google.jpg"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/Twitter.jpg"> </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="images">
<div class="pics">
<img src="GRProvider/Img.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="pics">
<img src="GRProvider/Img_2.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="diagram">
<div class="sample">
<img src="GRProvider/Img_3.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="sample">
<img src="GRProvider/Img_4.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main_content">
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#"> HOME </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> ABOUT US </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> CAREER </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="Slider">
<div class="slider_img">
<img src="GRProvider/Slider.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Info">
<div class="About_Us">
<p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting indutry. Lorem Ipsum has been 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bee
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bee
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has  Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsum............. </p>
</div>
<div class="button">
<button type="button"> READ MORE </button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="text">
<img src="GRProvider/Img_4.jpg" />
<h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
<h5> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any  
varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do 
feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae 
consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, 
eros leo molestie velit, nonegestas augue nulla </h5>
</div>
<div class="text">
<img src="GRProvider/Img_5.jpg" />
<h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
<h5> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any  
varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do 
feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae 
consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, 
eros leo molestie velit, nonegestas augue nulla </h5>
</div>
<div class="text">
<img src="GRProvider/Img_6.jpg" />
<h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
<h5> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any  
varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do 
feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae 
consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, 
eros leo molestie velit, nonegestas augue nulla </h5>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<h6> Copyright by Bitsprovider.com </h6>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code (mystyle.css)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #1e93a5;
    width: 80% auto;
}
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.center {
    float: left;
    width: 80% auto;
}
.header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.heading {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
h2 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 25%;
}
.socialmedia {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
.images {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 18%;
}
.pics img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.diagram {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 18%;
}
.sample img {
    width: 100%;
}
.main_content {
    float: left;
    position: static;
    width: 60%;
}
.navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation > ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation > ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 25%;
}
.navigation > ul li a {
    background-color: #2dacbe;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.slider {
    float: left;
    width: 1%;
}
.slider > img {
    width: 139%;
}
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 11%;
}
a {
    border: 1px solid #0e8393;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.info {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.About_Us {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
p {
    background-color: #2ea4b6;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
.button {
    float: right;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.text {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.text > img {
}
h4 {
    background-color: #263270;
    color: #fff;
    width: 93%;
}
h5 {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
h6 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: 1 it should be `margin:auto`, not `width` and 2 the elements are floated left, so they will not display centered anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help centering a div class on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881384/need-help-centering-a-div-class-on-page)

Comment: a margin of 20% on each side would also mean your content could only be 60% not 80%

Answer (score 1):

1 - Remove all your `float:left;`.
2 - Delete you div wrapper
3 - Put a 80% width on your content and use `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the unnecessary divs, you only need two to achieve what you are doing.
Refrain from using `body` for layouting because you can make a lot of unneccesary mistakes using it.

In the following CSS - code the `body` sets only the background color, the `wrapper` floats in the center with 20% margin on both sides and you are left with the header to do as you please.

Please refrain using `float` until you find a actual need to use it. Read up on w3schools excellent CSS-tutorials. http://www.w3schools.com/css/

```
    body {
    background-color: #1e93a5;
    }

    .wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto; // Shortcode for Margin: 0 (top), auto (right), 0 (bottom), auto (left)
    }

    .header {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: auto`, `width: 80% auto`doesn't center your container as you think. Also your `wrapper`class seems pretty useless to me. You don't need all those `float: left`s.

Comment: It's not working.. Can anyone suggest me any other answer.?

Comment: So what to use in replacement of those float: left.

Comment: @dani_developer I would try reorganizing your containers, you don't need that many layers of divs in order to make it work. In your code:

    `.wrapper { float: left; width: 100%}`

You're telling your div to fully cover it's parent then you're forcing it to the left, which is pointless since it already covers all of the space it can. I can't code it all for you so you can call my answer relevant. It is relevant but you need to rethink your html in order for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

For the div to center itself on the page, use the css

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

Remove any other unnecessary things, you don't need them. Let me know if it works.